# How to understand Commands used in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to understand the commands which are used for doing anything in Ubuntu means starting from sudo, apt-get, to everything .I want to have the knowledge of commands used in Ubuntu.I have searched Google for this stuff and found something related to shell scripting.Please help me out from where to start this, I want to expertise over the terminal commands.I don`t know where this expertise is going to be used but I want to learn as it attracts me.Please give me the resources, e books and the forums where i can post my doubts and queries.

Comment: Here's another nifty website: http://explainshell.com/

Answer (score 4):

Each and every Linux distribution has a compiled manual for each command itself. You can simply open a terminal by hitting <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then type `man command-name` to open the manual to learn more about a specific command and what is does. (e.g.: If you need to know about `ls`.. then type `man ls` and hit, magic happens!).

You may also refer **[Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)** to learn more

Answer (score 2):

Best place to start: Man pages. In the terminal type `man [command]` This will bring up the manual page for that command. (eg. `man apt-get`) More information can be found [here](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~guide/help/man.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn how to use the terminal, you just have to start with getting a good understanding of the basics and work your way through it.

You will find many good basic guides and tutorials through Google. I will list a few to begin with.

- [UsingTheTerminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) (Official Ubuntu Documentation)
- [Learning The Shell](http://www.linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php)
- [Linux Command Reference Guide](http://www.perpetualpc.net/srtd_commands_rev.html)

There are also pretty good Youtube videos for absolute beginners:

- [Basic Linux Shell Commands - Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nx4v4XziEHw)
- [Eli the Computer Guy - Basic Linux Tasks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnSUX2otYos)

When I first started using Linux, I found the manual pages confusing and hard to use. But if you learn how to master them, they become a very useful aspect of the terminal.

I don't remember every command I ever used.. I've got the command [apropos](http://www.linfo.org/apropos.html) and google for that :) Enjoy the terminal!

Answer (score 1):

Another good place to start is the book [Introduction to the Command Line](http://en.flossmanuals.net/command-line/) from [FLOSS Manuals](http://www.flossmanuals.net/).

Note that this manual is not restricted to Ubuntu, and you'll learn how to do a lot of things from the command line using several programs, some of which you might need to isntall in your Ubuntu if you want to use them. No problem, as the book will show you how to install programs as well.